# How to skew a Mac's clock 10 minutes while still keeping it "synchronized"?

Tags: macos, mac, time, clock, ntp

My wife is always running late. How can I skew her Mac's clock 10 minutes while still keeping it "synchronized"?

I looked at the `fudge` setting of [`/etc/ntp.conf`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man5/ntp.conf.5.html) but it's only for a Reference Clock and I'm not even sure it's still available in OS X 10.7.

Any ideas for how to achieve this?

Comment: I wonder if there's some way to 'emulate' a NTP server thats slow... Then just set your wife's computer to use that.

Comment: Better off teaching her consequences. (In a nonmean way. Every action has a reaction)

Comment: @kobaltz :) Yea, i'm also trying the (dis)incentive route to help her learn how to prepare ahead of time (and get accustom to being prepared) instead of always rushing to get out the door but i was also wanting to give her some extra help by setting the clocks that she uses ahead.

Comment: Could you create a timezone in your house?

Comment: @Aron That's an excellent idea. I think it's exactly the right way to go about it. Gonna try that. Thanks